# ¿Cómo unir varios txt en uno añadiendo un prefijo en cada línea usando python?

Tags: python, lista, fileoutputstream

Tengo varios txt, cada uno de ellos, una única línea.
Quiero unirlos todos en uno, siendo cada uno de ellos una línea, y añadiendo al  principio de cada línea:

```
> texto0\tX\t(contenido txt0)   
> texto1\tX\t(contenido txt1)
>         (...)
```

Para ello he creado el siguiente código en python:

```
import glob
  
outfilename = '/home/.../completo.txt'
        
read_files = glob.glob('/home/.../todos/*txt')
        
with open(outfilename, "wb") as outfile:
    #for i in range(3):
    for f in read_files:
       with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

No consigo hacer el .write de manera que me devuelva el texto con el formato que necesito.
Lo he intentado usando `for i in range(len(file))` y cosas por el estilo, pero en ninguna de ellas consigo el resultado indicado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Algo como esto?

```
import glob

outfilename = '/home/.../completo.txt'
read_files = glob.glob('/home/.../todos/*txt')
        
with open(outfilename, "w") as outfile:
    for n, f in enumerate(read_files):
       with open(f, "r") as infile:
           txt = "> texto{}\tX\t{}".format(n, infile.read())
           outfile.write(txt)
```

La línea que define la variable `txt` le asigna una cadena que contiene el prefijo que (creo) quieres añadir delante de cada fichero. Ese prefijo se construye usando el valor de la variable `n` que, va tomando valores 0, 1, etc. gracias al `enumerate`. Finalmente la variable contiene el contenido del fichero completo (cuyo contenido se supone que es una sola línea, como especificas en la pregunta).

No me queda muy claro no obstante si realmente quieres que el prefijo sea la cadena "texto0", "texto1", etc.. o si quieres que sean los nombres de los ficheros. Si es este segundo caso sería aún más sencillo:

```
    for f in read_files:
       with open(f, "r") as infile:
           txt = "> {}\tX\t{}".format(f, infile.read())
           outfile.write(txt)
```

Comment: Me devuelve este error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unir_txt.py", line 10, in <module>
    outfile.write(txt)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Y si añado outfile.write(str(txt)), sigue manteniendo el error

Comment: Ah, claro, que no me fijé que estabas abriendo los ficheros en modo binario. Realmente, si contienen solo texto, no veo necesidad de abrirlos en modo binario, así que he editado la respuesta para quitar la "b" a la hora de abrir el fichero. Si ves que esto te da problemas (lo que puede suceder si el texto de los ficheros no usa utf-8) avisa y edito de nuevo para hacerlo a través de los encodings apropiados

Comment: Si, así está perfecto, muchas gracias!

Comment: Al hacerlo con un path donde la cantidad de txt es mayor, el problema es que no me copia todos los txt. Es decir, si en mi path están 0.txt, 1.txt, 2.txt, ... 1000.txt, al crear ese nuevo txt, me aparece 

texto0
texto2
texto5
texto6

Sin sentido alguno

Comment: El orden en que ves los ficheros "desde fuera de python" depende de tu operativo y de las opciones que tenga a la hora de mostrar un directorio. Puedes verlos ordenados por fecha, por nombre, etc. Supongo que los estás viendo ordenados por nombre. En cambio glob los muestra en el orden en que el sistema se los da, que vete tú a saber cuál es. Si quieres que salgan ordenados por nombre basta que cambies en el bucle el for por: `for f in sorted(read_files):`

Comment: Me devuelve el siguiente error
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unir_canciones.py", line 8, in <module>
    for n, f in sorted(read_files):
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: Perdón, creí que estabas usando la segunda versión de mi código que usa directamente los nombres de los ficheros en lugar de crear nuevos nombres con la secuencia "texto{n}". Pero entonces no encuentro sentido a lo que te ocurre, ya que las cadenas que vas generando "texto{n}" no dependen del orden en que glob() te devuelva las cosas, ya que se van creando secuencialmente. No debería ocurrir eso de que te salte números (si es que los salta, que no me queda claro qué ocurre). ¿Y si mejor abres una nueva pregunta dando más detalles de lo que pasa, con el código que estás usando?

Comment: Tienes razón, lo he revisado mal, si que están todos los textos, solo que cuando en el editor de textos lo pongo de modo que se muestra el texto línea a línea, hay algunas que no tienen salto de línea, quiero decir:

texto0   X      (....) y texto1     X       (....) están en la misma línea, no se si me explico.
Puede que en `txt = "> texto{}\tX\t{}".format(n, infile.read())` le falte añadir un \n al final de la estructura? gracias!

Comment: El código que te puse en la respuesta estaba dando por hecho que cada uno de tus ficheros .txt contenía una y solo una línea de texto, y que esa línea incluía al final un retorno de carro. Parece que en algunos de tus ficheros tal retorno de carro no está presente. Pero si me confirmas que aún así todos tienen una sola línea puedo editar la respuesta para procesar correctamente esos retornos de carro del final y asegurar que todos usen uno. (si añades un \n como tú dices puedes encontrar casos en que salgan dos, dejando líneas en blanco)

Comment: Así es, gracias por tu paciencia! Ya está todo como quería